# Is there any way to perform this "cast" of a void ptr to a structure pointer inline in C?

Tags: c, void-pointers

*Please note that the following code is a contrived example of accessing a struct via a void pointer and is otherwise meaningless*. My question is, is there an alternate way to cast a void pointer to a struct pointer inline (by using a (CAST*) style syntax? E.G. can I avoid the line `S_TEST *tester_node_ptr = tester_node.next;` and somehow cast directly in the printf call?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
//Set up our data structure
typedef struct test{
    int field1;
    int field2;
    char name[50];
    void *next; // We will use this void * to refer to another struct test "node" for demo purposes
} S_TEST;



int main(void)
{
    S_TEST tester_node;
    S_TEST tester_node2;
    tester_node.field1 = 55;
    tester_node.field2 = 25;
    strcpy(tester_node.name, "First Node");
    tester_node.next = &tester_node2; // We put the addr of the second node into the void ptr
    tester_node2.field1 = 775;
    tester_node2.field2 = 678;
    strcpy(tester_node2.name, "Second Node");
    tester_node2.next = NULL; // End of list


    S_TEST *tester_node_ptr = tester_node.next;
    printf("The second node's name is: %s", tester_node_ptr->name);


    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may. It's as simple as this

```
((S_TEST *)tester_node.next)->name
```

Though I'd say using a named variable and relying on the implicit conversion is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should probably just declare `struct test *next` instead of `void *next`. But anyway:

```
printf("The second node's name is: %s", ((S_TEST *)tester_node.next)->name);
```